# Data usage in MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, network, data

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my MacBook Pro?

My normal data usage for 1 day is shown on the image below:

[image]

But in the past few days and for just 1 hour (I have no idea why) my data usage spikes up and its totally unbelievable.

[image]

My usage is just the same as before, nothing change,
and also lately I have been using 3G speed because of some network problem
so I wonder why the usage had been GB when it should just be in MB?

Can someone explain why this happened and also advise on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave Activity Monitor open, you ought to be able to sort by Sent or Received Byes to catch the culprit...

[image]